# How to pick, display two images on two UIImageViews, and then upload these two chosen images to Firebase Database and Storage?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-storage, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to pick two different images on two imageView's on one ViewController, display them, and after pushing the button save picked images to firebase database and storage to its particular user. My code only able to upload one picked image, not two different, I understand that the problem with UIImagePickerController part, but how can I resolve it. Full code of viewController is below. Please help!!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SettingProfileViewController.handleSelectProfileImageView(sender:)))
        profilePhoto.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        profilePhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let wallTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SettingProfileViewController.handleSelectWallpaperImageView(sender:)))
        wallpaperPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(wallTapGesture)
        wallpaperPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        profilePhoto.layer.cornerRadius = 60
        profilePhoto.clipsToBounds = true

    }

    weak var activeImageView:UIImageView? = nil


    @objc func handleSelectWallpaperImageView(sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
        guard let sendingImageView = sender.view as? UIImageView else {
            print("Ooops, received this gesture not from an ImageView")
            return
        }
        activeImageView = sendingImageView
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "New Photo", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Камера", style: .default, handler: { action in
            self.showCamera()
        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Альбом ", style: .default, handler: {action in
            self.showAlbum()
        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Отмена", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    @objc func handleSelectProfileImageView(sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
        guard let sendingImageView = sender.view as? UIImageView else {
            print("Ooops, received this gesture not from an ImageView")
            return
        }
        activeImageView = sendingImageView

        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "New Photo", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Камера", style: .default, handler: { action in
            self.showCamera()

        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Альбом ", style: .default, handler: {action in
            self.showAlbum()

        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Отмена", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func showCamera() {

        let cameraPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        cameraPicker.delegate = self
        cameraPicker.sourceType = .camera

        present(cameraPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func showAlbum(){
           let cameraPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        cameraPicker.delegate = self 
           cameraPicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

           present(cameraPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }




    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage{
//             selectedImage = image
            activeImageView?.image = image
//            currentImage = image
        }
    }



    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
         dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    ///для того чтобы загруженные фото, отображались на ProfileViewController
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "profileVC" {
            let destination = segue.destination as! ProfileViewController
            destination.wImage = activeImageView?.image


        }
    }




    @IBAction func saveTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let did = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://crut-6c67c.appspot.com").child("profile_Image").child(did)
        if let pImage = self.activeImageView?.image, let imageData = pImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
            storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: {(metadata, Error) in
                if Error != nil, metadata != nil {
                    return
                }

                storageRef.downloadURL { (url: URL?,error: Error?) in
                    if let profileImageUrl = url?.absoluteString{
                        db.collection("suppliers").document("ip").collection("ipinfo").document(did).setData(["Profile Image":profileImageUrl], merge: true)
                    }
                }
            })
        }


        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: nil)
        let profileViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(identifier:profile.Storyboard.profileViewController) as? ProfileViewController
        self.view.window?.rootViewController = profileViewController
        self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an instance variable in your viewController i.e.

```
private var isProfilePhotoSelecting = true
```

When user tap on profileImageView in handleSelectProfileImageView method set isProfilePhotoSelecting to true i.e.

```
@objc func handleSelectProfileImageView(sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
        guard let sendingImageView = sender.view as? UIImageView else {
            print("Ooops, received this gesture not from an ImageView")
            return
        }

        // Updated the image under consideration
        isProfilePhotoSelecting = true

        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "New Photo", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Камера", style: .default, handler: { action in
            self.showCamera()

        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Альбом ", style: .default, handler: {action in
            self.showAlbum()

        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Отмена", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

And on wallpaperImageView tapping in handleSelectWallpaperImageView method set isProfilePhotoSelecting to false i.e.

```
@objc func handleSelectWallpaperImageView(sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
        guard let sendingImageView = sender.view as? UIImageView else {
            print("Ooops, received this gesture not from an ImageView")
            return
        }
        // Updated the image under consideration
        isProfilePhotoSelecting = false

        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "New Photo", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Камера", style: .default, handler: { action in
            self.showCamera()
        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Альбом ", style: .default, handler: {action in
            self.showAlbum()
        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Отмена", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Then update your imagePickerDelegate to :

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            if isProfilePhotoSelecting {
                profilePhoto.image = image
            } else {
                wallpaperPhoto.image = image
            }
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

This will help you set both your images to their respective imageView. Then in saveTapped(_:) method you can check both imageViews for images and upload them i.e. Your saveTapped() method should look like this

```
@IBAction func saveTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let did = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://crut-6c67c.appspot.com")
    if let profileImage = self.profilePhoto.image, let imageData = profileImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
        let profileStorage = storageRef.child("profile_Image").child(did)
        profileStorage.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: {(metadata, Error) in
            if Error != nil, metadata != nil {
                return
            }

            profileStorage.downloadURL { (url: URL?,error: Error?) in
                if let profileImageUrl = url?.absoluteString {
                    db.collection("suppliers").document("ip").collection("ipinfo").document(did).setData(["Profile Image":profileImageUrl], merge: true)
                }
            }
        })
    }



    if let wallpaperImage = self.wallpaperPhoto.image, let imageData = wallpaperImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
        let wallpaperStorage = storageRef.child("wallpaper_Image").child(did)
        wallpaperStorage.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: {(metadata, Error) in
            if Error != nil, metadata != nil {
                return
            }

            wallpaperStorage.downloadURL { (url: URL?,error: Error?) in
                if let wallpaperImageUrl = url?.absoluteString {

                    // Do your stuff with wallpaper image url here

                }
            }
        })
    }


    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: nil)
    let profileViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(identifier:profile.Storyboard.profileViewController) as? ProfileViewController
    self.view.window?.rootViewController = profileViewController
    self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

**Note**: This will not wait for the images to upload as you are waiting for them to upload. But it depends on your usecase if you want to wait until the image  uploading completes and then move to ProfileViewController, you can use **DispatchGroup** for that purpose.

Comment: unfortunately, it keeps uploading the same image from profilePhoto to Firebase Database as a profile and wallpaper

Comment: basically, your logic was right, but needed a few corrections, I updated my own answer above, it works. But, thank you, basically you showed me the way I should think about resolving this problem.

Comment: @Emtel ohh yes, I just showed how it can be done, it works fine if respective storageRef will be used.

Comment: I updated my answer to use respective storage for profile and wallpaper image.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your saving the last choosen image on `activeImageView` and passing that to `Firebase`, hence only one image is getting uploaded.

Instead create and `Array` and both the images choosen from `handleSelectWallpaperImageView` and `handleSelectWallpaperImageView`, then loop through the `Array` and send to `Firebase`.

Check this for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49934285/1244403

Comment: I don't really understand how can I apply it to my code. can you please explain more explicitly relative to my code.

Answer (score 0):

Created option Boolean variable

```
var isProfilePhotoSelecting:Bool?

@objc func handleSelectWallpaperImageView(sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
isProfilePhotoSelecting = false
/// 
other code
}
@objc func handleSelectProfileImageView(sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
isProfilePhotoSelecting = true
/// 
other code
}
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage{

            if isProfilePhotoSelecting == true {
                profilePhoto.image = image
            }else {
                wallpaperPhoto.image = image
            }

        }
    }
```

In the saveTapped need to be added storage references to each chosen image and its respective database.

```
@IBAction func saveTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let did = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://crut-6c67c.appspot.com").child("profile_Image").child(did)
        if let profileImage = self.profilePhoto.image, let imageData = profileImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1){
            storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: {(metadata, Error) in
                if Error != nil, metadata != nil {
                    return
                }
                storageRef.downloadURL { (url: URL?, error: Error?) in
                    if let profileImageUrl = url?.absoluteString {
                        db.collection("suppliers").document("ip").collection("ipinfo").document(did).setData(["Profile Image":profileImageUrl], merge: true)
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        let wallStoreRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://crut-6c67c.appspot.com").child("Wallpaper_Image").child(did)
        if let wallpaperImage = self.wallpaperPhoto.image, let imageData = wallpaperImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
            wallStoreRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: {(metadata, Error) in
                if Error != nil, metadata != nil {
                    return
                }

                wallStoreRef.downloadURL { (url: URL?,error: Error?) in
                    if let wallpaperImageUrl = url?.absoluteString {
                        // Do your stuff with wallpaper image url here
                    db.collection("suppliers").document("ip").collection("ipinfo").document(did).setData(["Wallpaper Image":wallpaperImageUrl], merge: true)



                    }
                }
            })
        }
```